# Router-link not working in Vuetify Dialog

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm using the Vuetify "Bottom sheet" as big navigation-menu for my Vue-App. In the bottom-sheet I have a list and each item links to its respective route. The route changes, but the state is only updated the first time I click an element and doesn't change if I click another item in the list.

As a quickfix I fire a method in a click-event instead of using the `<router-link>`. Here I close the dialog, dispatch the action and afterwords push to the route:

```
linkToArt (item) {
    this.dialog = false
    this.loadSingleCollection(item.name)
    this.$router.push({ name: 'collection', params: {id: item.id } })
}
```

This works, but I want to update the state in the component "collection" itself. Is there a way in a dialog to push directly to the respective route via router-link and update the state there? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Anyway, both the places its gonna  dispatch an action to store, do you need any manipulation to "item"?, If not, stick with this approach, if you dont want to expose the data in url params stick with this approach. Still you want to update store from collection, go ahead..

Comment: Thx for your response. I can't send the data in the params, because the item doesnt't contain it. The items are a list of collections. Each collection contains about 100 items itself. They have to be loaded in the respective component after the push. I wan't to dispatch in the "collection" component and not in the "dialog" component but this doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you please share your component code ?

Comment: I changed to navigation drawer. I probably can do that with the dialog component, but the whole emitting to parent component and router-view is to much. Thanks anyway!